# Dashcode project opening in xcode problem

Tags: dashcode

If we make our Dashcode application open in Xcode then are we making a native app....

Comment: That is a statement, not a question ;-) Please explain in more detail what your problem is, I don't understand it.

Comment: Oh i forgot a "?" over there, its a question and i am asking if i open  my application made in Dashcode in Xcode and continue working then will it remain a web application?

Answer (score 1):

Dashcode is an IDE, a tool or set of tools for developing Mac Widgets, web based iPxxx applications and Webkit based Web applications. In Dashcode JavaScript, CSS and HTML are used to develop these applications.

XCode is an IDE for developing native Mac applications and iPxxx applications usually but not exclusively with Objective-c and an interface builder for the graphical elements.

A Dashcode project is in reality a set of file in a folder, but the Mac Finder makes it look like a bundle. If you right click the project and click on open project you will just see all the files in the project.

Opening the Dashcode project in XCode doesn't do anything, i just tried it, but even if you did XCode will not perform an magical transformation and turn JS/CSS/HTML into Objective-C and therefore it will not turn it into what i think you mean by native app. To do that you will need to learn Objexctive-C cocoa and the XCode programming tools and interface.

In answer to oyur added comment not it will not change any code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know: can we treat a DashCode app as native app, and run on simulator and/or real iOS devices.

From my point of view, the answer is: YES

I think what you asked can be answered using [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/build-web-apps-iphone-using-dashcode).

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken a little more input towards this may be nice. If you use PhoneGap in Xcode then you can make your web app a native app with very little effort. I found that porting my skills from mobile web development to Xcode was something I didn't have the time to put out upfront so to get my app out there right away, PhoneGap was my answer. 
I hope this helps, but do know that it is not going to be as efficient of an app built this way.